# Jenkins inside container

Tags: docker, jenkins

Before someone shouts at me saying that Jenkins has a official docker container, I would like to say that I'm playing/testing anything that I can think of.

I have a container(php:7.2-apache) where I'm installing Jenkins and I have a problem starting the service to run Jenkins.

I have tried to start the service with `CMD service jenkins start` but when I run the container `docker-compose up -d` the log show me this and after this the container is stooped with exit code 0

> test_1  | Correct java version found
>   test_1  | Starting Jenkins Automation Server: jenkins.

Could some one help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could some one help me with this? I feel curiosity to know the reason

The reason is that you are starting Jenkins as a service which will run in the background.

The Docker container lives as long as the process running by the `CMD` is still alive. In this case, the process simply starts the jenkins
service and exists. This will cause the container to exit as soon as the command `service jenkins start` finishes.

Take a look at the [jenkins.sh](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/jenkins.sh) script used by the official jenkins image to start jenkins.